# How to render directive in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

for example there is a directive

```js
(function() {
    angular.module("mydir", []).directive("mydir", mydir);

    function mydir() {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            templateUrl: "app/components/myDir/myDir.template.html",
        };
    }
}());
```

and in the controller I'm trying to do the following

```js
var temp = "<div mydir></div>";
var content = $compile(temp)({});
```

compile returns a div element, but would like to template of directive.

Comment: Why would you want to do it this way?  Why not let your template control the directives it renders?

Comment: I need to then transfer this template to print, and maybe there will be a few different $scope

Comment: @ВадимЦарегородцев, well - the template is being retrieved asynchronously, so, it's not available immediately after `$compile`, Using `template` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Directives are named using camel case, however, in the HTML they use a hyphen (myDir -> my-dir).

```
<div my-dir></dir>
```

Comment: I'm in a hurry and made ​​a mistake , the directive is spelled correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me.

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('defaultmod',[]);
app.directive('mydir',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'AE',
        template:'<span>hello</span>'
    };
});

app.controller('defaultctrl', function($scope,$compile){
    var temp = "<div mydir></div>";
    var content = $compile(temp)({});
    alert(content[0].outerHTML);
});
```

HTML

```
  <div ng-app="defaultmod">
        <div ng-controller="defaultctrl">

        </div>
    </div>
```

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vcps7yy0/

Comment: possible 'template' works a little differently than 'templateUrl'

Comment: I don't think there should be.. I may be wrong though.. I can't test with a templateURL in jsfiddle.. need an environment.. Need some time.. in the mean time.. perhaps you can try with template in your code to rule out any other errors..